# Including descriptions in a CV

Tags: postdocs, cv

I am a graduate student and am updating my CV for my upcoming postdoc search. While doing so, I found that it looks nicer (format-wise) with just the names of the projects, service activities, awards, etc., than it did with a 1-2 sentence description over 2-3 lines.

I could remove the descriptions entirely, or I could shorten them to a single line. In either case it would be more consistent and more nicely presented. As far as I have seen, there is no convention on what should have a description and what shouldn't.

What rules of thumb do you have for whether or not to describe things on your CV? If you do add descriptions, how do you do so without it turning into padding?

Comment: What exactly are you describing? Are you describing one or two sentences of research and projects, or are you doing this even for awards, service activities and so on? The former seems okay (though 2-3 lines is a little excessive IMO), whereas the latter seems unnecessary. A website would be a better place for "padding" things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do both, meaning I would create **a long version** with 2-3 lines of description **and a short version** without (or describing only 1-2 projects). The trick is to **submit the right version for each application** (based on what the postdoc ad is asking for).

(In case this helps: for me the "winner" was the short, 1-page version with 3 lines of description for two projects and an awful lot of links to Google Scholar, ResearchGate, degree certificate from my uni, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in both industry and academia, it is my impression that people tend to quickly gloss over resumes and CV's, as time is a valuable commodity and such people are already busy with reading so many resumes/CV's amongst other things they have to do.  Your best bet is to keep it short and concise on paper (i.e., short bullet points with relatively short sentences) as opposed to long, potentially run-on sentences.  As has been mentioned, it's a good thing to tailor your resume/CV to the job/postdoc position that you are applying to, but in general, especially if you have more things to put on your CV, you'll want shorter and more concise descriptions.  If you want to describe more in detail, you can always do this on a website or LinkedIn page.  You'll also have an opportunity to go more into detail about your past experience pertinent to the job at hand in the interview process.